# How to redirect out side the external folder(user created folder inside the controller) in cakePHP3

Tags: php, redirect, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have created the v1 folder inside the controller when user login outside the vl folder and redirected to v1 folder. There is no issue here. While i logout the page again redirect to login page that is outside the v1 folder but it also happens it checks only inside the folder it not came outside of v1 folder.

Login redirection:

```
$this->redirect(['controller' => 'v1/threads', 'action' => 'index']);
```

logout redirection:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Logout',['controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'Login']); ?>
```

please any one help on this issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting `../admin` in the controller?